# phantom command error

Tags: phantom

At wikipedia this

```
<math>\phantom{-}\frac{8}{2}=\phantom{-}4</math>
```

should produce

`$\phantom{-}\frac{8}{2}=\phantom{-}4$`

(I dont know how to make that display correctly here either)

but I get an error message

Failed to parse (unknown function "\phantom"): {\displaystyle \phantom{-}\frac{8}{2}=\phantom{-}4 }

I have no idea whats going on. It used to work fine. What can I do to fix it.

Comment: Which I guess Wikipedia doesnt use. So what package does Wikipedia use and what is the replacement for phantom?

Comment: MediaWiki uses a subset of AMS-LaTeX markup, a superset of LaTeX markup which is in turn a superset of TeX markup, for mathematical formulae. It generates PNG images by default. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Math/Help:Formula

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke \phantom is not amsmath specific, it is defined in latex.ltx

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke `\phantom` has been in `plain.tex` from day one and it has been imported in LaTeX essentially verbatim. It is *not* necessary to load `amsmath` for it. On the other hand, if a JavaScript implementation of a LaTeX interpreter lacks `\phantom`, there's little that can be done on the LaTeX side.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thank you. Removed.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Removed.