Can we make a true \phantom?
My question is: "Is it possible to create a general "true" \phantom command that makes the inputted content invisible while preserving the original typesetting?".
I do not consider coloring the text or math content white to be a solution. This is not a question of the type "how can I typeset this", and as such you should not interpret the following example as a typesetting problem I don't know how to solve (this not a duplicate of this question, I know about \mathrel). This is a question about the macro and typesetting systems. If this is not possible, an explanation of why is welcomed.
Here is a MWE to see why the existing \phantom command doesn't satisfy the requirements I made.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
4 &= 2 + 2 \\              % Equation (1): 4 = 2 + 2
4 &= 2 {+} 2 \\            % Equation (2): 4 = 2+2
4 &= 2 \phantom{+} 2 \\    % Equation (3): 4 = 2 2
4 &= 2 \phantom{{}+{}} 2   % Equation (4): 4 = 2   2
\end{align}
\end{document}

Inside equations (1) and (4) the + symbol is interpreted as a binary operator. Inside equations (2) and (3) the + symbol is not interpreted as a binary operator, thus requiring less spacing. A "true" phantom command would be a command \Phantom such that 4 = 2 \Phantom{+} 2 would typeset like equation (4).
Unsurprisingly, if we track down the definition of \phantom in the LaTeX2ε source code we see that the content is placed inside an \hbox which knows nothing about the original context (see ltmath.dtx lines 83, 97, 104, 106).

I would be surprised if anyone had ever tried to \phantom a naked operator before.

it's easy enough to automatically fix the case you show and automatically insert the \mathrel but harder with a general subterm with different added space at each end, and harder still if you need inline math white space to stretch or shrink as it would unboxed

@JohnKormylo I'd say it's rather common eg to make negative and positive numbers align in some constructs using a \phantom{-}3  aligning with a -2  eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/599758/1090

@DavidCarlisle - I stand surprised,

OTOH, a unary - doesn't use the same spacing as a binary -.  It acts like a normal character.

Why is coloring white not a solution for you? ie \mathcolor{white}{+} in math?

You can use the same mechanism that amsmath uses for \overset and \underset. It can distinguish between relation and operation symbols; anything else is considered ordinary.
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tph}[1]{%
  \binrel@{#1}\binrel@@{\phantom{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
4 &= 2 + 2 \\              % Equation (1): 4 = 2 + 2
4 &= 2 \tph{+} 2 \\        % Equation (2): 4 = 2 + 2
4 &\tph{=}2 + 2 \\
4 &\tph{=}2 \tph{+} 2
\end{align}

\end{document}


For historical reasons, the definition of \binrel@ is in amsbsy.sty:
\def\binrel@#1{\begingroup
  \setboxz@h{\thinmuskip0mu
    \medmuskip\m@ne mu\thickmuskip\@ne mu
    \setbox\tw@\hbox{$#1\m@th$}\kern-\wd\tw@
    ${}#1{}\m@th$}%
  \edef\@tempa{\endgroup\let\noexpand\binrel@@
    \ifdim\wdz@<\z@ \mathbin
    \else\ifdim\wdz@>\z@ \mathrel
    \else \relax\fi\fi}%
  \@tempa
}
\let\binrel@@\relax

It's an interesting exercise to understand what the code does.

Just in case it's not clear to the casual reader, you may want to note that \tph operates on a single item and hence that it won't work properly on. say. 4 &\tph{=2+} 2.

@Mico That's what the OP wanted. Your version doesn't really work with arbitrary input, because it adds empty Ord atoms here and there, even where they might spoil the spacing. For instance, 1+\sin x and 1+{}\sin x produce different spacing.

@egreg: well, the original question was about "command that makes the inputted content invisible while preserving the original typesetting". Single item and math mode are there only to illustrate the problem, just an mvce to reproduce the issue.

I assume the OP was asking for a universal solution.

Does
\newcommand\Phantom[1]{\phantom{{}#1{}}}

satisfy your design requirement(s) -- at least for (reasonably ordinary) math typesetting jobs?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'gather*' environments
\newcommand\Phantom[1]{\phantom{{}#1{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
4 &= 2 + 2.           \\  
\Phantom{4} &= 2+2.   \\  
4 &\Phantom{= 2+}2.   \\   
4 &= \Phantom{2}+2.   \\           
4 &= 2 \Phantom{+} 2. \\
4 &= 2 + \Phantom{2}. 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
4 = 2 + 2.           \\  
\Phantom{4} = 2+2.   \\  
4 \Phantom{= 2+}2.   \\   
4 = \Phantom{2}+2.   \\           
4 = 2 \Phantom{+} 2. \\
4 = 2 + \Phantom{2}. 
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}

